# How to get the key from a Firebase data snapshot?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm able to query my `users` array with an e-mail address and return the user's account info:

```
users.orderByChild('email').equalTo(authData.user.email).once('value').then(function(snapshot) {
        console.log(snapshot.val());
        console.log(snapshot.key); // 'users'
        console.log(snapshot.child('email').key); 'email'
        ...
```

[image]

How do I get the key (`-KiBBDaj4fBDRmSS3j0r`). `snapshot.key` returns `users`. `snapshot.child('email').key` returns `email`. The key doesn't appear to be a child, i.e., it appears to be in between `users` and `email`.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
var key = Object.keys(snapshot.val())[0];
```

Ref: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys

> The Object.keys() method returns an array of a given object's own
>   enumerable properties, in the same order as that provided by a
>   for...in loop (the difference being that a for-in loop enumerates
>   properties in the prototype chain as well).

Comment: Fast response! Thanks!

Answer (score 33):

**Realtime database**:

For this you can simple use: *snapshot.key*

snapshot = [firebase.database.DataSnapshot](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.DataSnapshot)

```
this.app.database()
        .ref('/data/')
        .on('value', function(snapshot) {
            const id = snapshot.key;

            //----------OR----------//
            const data = snapshot.val() || null;
            if (data) {
              const id = Object.keys(data)[0];
            }
        });
```

**Firestore**:

*snapshot.id*

snapshot = [firebase.firestore.DocumentSnapshot](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.DocumentSnapshot)

```
this.app.firestore()
        .collection('collection')
        .doc('document')
        .onSnapshot(function(snapshot) {
            const id = snapshot.id;

            //----------OR----------//
            const data = snapshot.data() || null;
            if (data) {
              const id = Object.keys(data)[0];
            }
        });
```

Comment: This is the most correct answer in comparison to other answers.

Answer (score 6):

`users.orderByChild('email').equalTo(authData.user.email)` is a Query ([doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Query)) that you have built by "chaining together one or more of the filter methods". What is a bit specific with your query is that **it returns a dataSnapshot with only one child**, since you query with `equalTo(authData.user.email)`.

As explained [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/lists-of-data#listen_for_value_events), in this exact case, you should loop over the returned dataSnapshot with `forEach()`:

> Attaching a value observer to a list of data will return the entire list of data as a single snapshot which you can then loop over to access individual children.
>
> **Even when there is only a single match for the query, the snapshot is
>   still a list**; it just contains a single item. To access the item, 
>   **you need to loop over the result**, as follows:
>
> ```
> ref.once('value', function(snapshot) {
>   snapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot) {
>     var childKey = childSnapshot.key;
>     var childData = childSnapshot.val();
>     // ...
>   });
> });
> ```

Comment: This is actually the way that is recommended in the Firebase docs!

Answer (score 5):

Similar to camden_kid, I used `Object.keys(arr)`, but in three lines:

```
var arr = snapshot.val();
var arr2 = Object.keys(arr);
var key = arr2[0];
console.log(key) // -KiBBDaj4fBDRmSS3j0r
```

Answer (score 3):

I found new way to get the data based on snapshot key -

```
 firebase.database().ref('events').once('value',(data)=>{
      //console.log(data.toJSON());
      data.forEach(function(snapshot){
        var newPost = snapshot.val();
        console.log("description: " + newPost.description);
        console.log("interest: " + newPost.interest);
        console.log("players: " + newPost.players);
        console.log("uid: " + newPost.uid);
        console.log("when: " + newPost.when);
        console.log("where: " + newPost.where);
      })
      })
```

Comment: I had the almost the same issue as the OP and ended doing this and other kinds of foreach/for and indeed the get the info but due to the scope I lost the values. Do you have a recommendation on that? It would be very helpful.