# Firebase infinite scroll proper solution?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have built a pretty complex list(s) in a component that all query the same way. When I hit the end of my list, I increase my fetch limit by 10... Everything was going great until I realized I am loading all the data over again (not just the new 10). I want to avoid all these reads to reduce costs - I am not sure if firebase ignores the data that is already loaded or not... My list is running quite smooth when I fetch the extra 10 every time but I don't know if behind the scenes things will come back to haunt me!

**UPDATE**

I have updated my code based off some helpful feedback and I believe I have things working how they should be. There is only one thing that I am concerned about. When I reach the bottom of my list after my first fetch I am passing all of the previous data to my action creator then concatinating it to the new fetched data. This repeats everytime I hit the bottom as the list grows. My list is going to have over 1000 records so I am worried about potential performance issues, should I be? Have a look at my new attempt below!

Original Attempt:

```
onEndReached = () => {
 const { searchFilterText, effectVal } = this.state;

   this.setState({
     strainFetchIndex: this.state.strainFetchIndex + 10
   }, () => {
     const offset = this.state.strainFetchIndex;

      if (searchFilterText === '') {
       this.props.strainsFetch(offset);
     } else if (searchFilterText === 'Hybrid' || searchFilterText === 'Salt' || searchFilterText === 'Initial') {
       this.props.filterStrainAction(searchFilterText, offset);
     } else if (searchFilterText === 'Effects') {
       this.props.filterByEffect(effectVal, offset);
     }
  });
}

//HERES 1 of 4 ACTION CREATORS WHERE I FETCH MORE DATA (ALL ARE SIMILAR)

    export const strainsFetch = (offset) => {
      const ting = offset || 1;
        return (dispatch) => {
          firebase.database().ref('/strains')
            .orderByKey()
            .limitToFirst(1 * ting)
            .on('value', snapshot => {
              dispatch({ type: STRAINS_FETCH_SUCCESS, payload: snapshot.val() });
            });
        };
      };
```

New attempt:

```
  onEndReached = () => {
    const { searchFilterText } = this.state;
    const { lastKey } = this.props;
    const currentStrains = this.props.strains;

      if (this.state.filterLabel === 'Favourites') {
        return null;
      }
      if (searchFilterText === '') {
        //here I pass all previous records along with the last key (last key comes from my action creator)
        this.props.strainsFetch(currentStrains, lastKey);
      } 
    }



    //ACTION CREATOR



    export const strainsFetch = (currentStrains, lastKey) => {
      if (!lastKey) {
        return (dispatch) => {
          // console.log('first Fetch');
          firebase.database().ref('/strains')
            .orderByKey()
            .limitToFirst(10)
            .on('value', snapshot => {
              const snap = snapshot.val();
              const snapKeys = Object.keys(snap);
              const createLastKey = snapKeys[9];

              dispatch({ type: STRAINS_FETCH_SUCCESS, payload: snapshot.val(), key: createLastKey });
            });
        };
      }
        return (dispatch) => {
          // console.log('subsequent Fetch');
          firebase.database().ref('/strains')
            .orderByKey()
            .startAt(`${lastKey}`)
            .limitToFirst(11)
            .on('value', snapshot => {
              const snap = snapshot.val();
              const snapKeys = Object.keys(snap)
              .slice(1);

              const results = snapKeys
                 .map((key) => snapshot.val()[key]);

              const createLastKey = snapKeys[snapKeys.length - 1];
              const concatStrains = _.concat(currentStrains, results);

              dispatch({ type: STRAINS_FETCH_SUCCESS, payload: concatStrains, key: createLastKey });
            });
        };
      };



      //HERE IS WHAT MY REDUCER LOOKS LIKE



    import {
      STRAINS_FETCH_SUCCESS
    } from '../actions/types';

    const INITIAL_STATE = {};

    export default (state = INITIAL_STATE, action) => {
      switch (action.type) {
        case STRAINS_FETCH_SUCCESS:
        // console.log(action.payload);
          return { strains: action.payload, lastKey: action.key };

        default:
          return state;
      }
    };
```

Is this a bad practice to repeatedly pass the previous data to my action creator over and over as the list continues to grow? Or is there a more efficient way to accomplish this?

Thanks everyone!

Cheers.

Comment: You need to provide an offset. Your first call will get items 0-10 during the fetch - a subsequent request would pass up `?offset=10` which starts from the tenth document.

Comment: Hi lux, I'm afraid I don't understand what you are trying to say. I am passing in an offset every time my list reaches the end. It increments the offset by 10 every time which loads 10 more items than before. @lux

Comment: endless scroll with Firebase is dramatic, because one needs to attach in reverse order. for example: https://apps-script-community-ar-a9405.firebaseapp.com/ (notice the numbers top right). if I remember that correctly, on subsequent requests one has to fetch 10+1, but skip 1.

Comment: Thanks martin, you're right... It seems to be a huge hassle to get this working properly... How would you recommend I get the last key to be my starting point for the next fetch?

Answer (score 0):

You're correct in that you are re-loading all of the old ones in addition to the new ones. If you only want to load the new ones, then you should use the `.startAt()` method, check out the [relevant docs here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/query-cursors#add_a_simple_cursor_to_a_query).

Your final setup would look something like:

```
export const strainsFetch = (offset) => {
    const startingIndex = offset || 1;
    const numRecordsToLoad = 10;
    return (dispatch) => {
        firebase.database().ref('/strains')
            .orderByKey()
            .startAt(startingIndex)
            .limitToFirst(numRecordsToLoad)
            .on('value', snapshot => {
                dispatch({ type: STRAINS_FETCH_SUCCESS, payload: snapshot.val() });
            });
    };
};
```

Comment: Hi Jeremy, thank you for confirming that. I am using the realtime database though, not cloud firestore which is where the link leads me. Can I still accomplish this?

Comment: @hugger Oops! Sorry about that, [here is the link for RTD](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/lists-of-data#filtering_data) docs for `.startAt()`... should be the same thing though.

Comment: Thank Jeremy! the start at would be the key of the last item, correct? if so what how would you recommend I get this value? I've been doing some research and there seems to be no clear solution to achieve this without SO MUCH CODE!! I wouldn't mind if it was for only one query but I have many... It seems pretty crazy to me how there is not a more efficient way to achieve paging like this.

Comment: @hugger Yep, startAt would be the key of the last item. The key is included in the snapshot you pull down, and the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43615466/how-to-get-the-key-from-a-firebase-data-snapshot) shows how for both RTD and Firestore - you'd just need to include the key in the action's payload instead of just `snapshot.val()` alone, and have your reducer handle getting that into the store with the rest of that value's information. Depending on how you have your store structured, that might involve a little bit of reworking the store structure

Comment: Hey @JeremyW! Thanks so much for the help. I think I have things working correctly without loading all of the data over and over again using the `startAt()`, I am just concerned with one thing... I have updated my question with my new attempt, mind checking it out?